# Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.7.dev, >= 2.3 on Pentestbox

Tags: ruby, metasploit

when I try to run metasploit on pentestbox last version I get the below error

> could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":   In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):     activesupport (= 4.2.11)    In Gemfile:     metasploit-framework x86-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.5, which depends on       activerecord (~> 4.2.6) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.10, which depends on         activesupport (= 4.2.10) x86-mingw32      rspec-rails x86-mingw32 was resolved to 3.8.2, which depends on       railties (>= 3.0) was resolved to 4.2.11, which depends on         activesupport (= 4.2.11) x86-mingw32  Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

I tried running the command "bundle update", but got this error

> Fetching nokogiri 1.10.1 (x86-mingw32) Installing nokogiri 1.10.1 (x86-mingw32) Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.7.dev, >= 2.3. An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.10.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.1'` succeeds before bundling

after that  I try run command "bundle install" I get same Error

Comment: what version of Ruby do you have?

Comment: ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [i386-mingw32]

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error in my Windows 10 and I was able to install the nokogori successfully. Below is my Ruby environment.

```
RubyGems Environment:
      - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
      - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x64-mingw32]
      - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby222-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
      - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby222-x64/bin/ruby.exe
      - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby222-x64/bin
      - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
      - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
        - x64-mingw32
      - GEM PATHS:
         - C:/Ruby222-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
```

To solved the issue I just updated my Gemfile. I added this line:
**gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.8'**

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10, I installed nokogiri prerelease version in which this is fixed.

```
gem inst nokogiri --pre
```

Then I changed the dependency in the gemfile.lock file:

```
nokogiri (1.11.0.rc2-x64-mingw32)
```

Reference:
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1961